# CentOS 6 - Make system aware of custom lib paths and missing base links

Tags: centos6

I am trying to compile libmemcached (1.0.7) on CentOS6, and keep getting the following warning:

```
...
checking for event.h... no
configure: WARNING: Unable to find libevent
...
```

I manually compiled libevent (2.0.19) and built it using the following configure line:

```
OPTIONS="--prefix=/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent"
```

Everything compiled and installed fine, but I couldn't figure out how to make the system aware that the lib files are in the custom `/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib`dir. I stumbled upon an [article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/) and read that I can make the system aware of custom lib paths by adding a custom file to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory:

```
# /etc/ld.so.conf.d/customApp.conf
/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib
```

Then I issued the `ldconfig` command and was able to confirm that `libevent` was included by issuing this command:

```
ldconfig -p | ack -i libevent
```

Seeing that libevent was now included in the ldconfig output, I figured I would be able to compile libmemcached and satisfy the aforementioned warning. Unfortunately it did not. So I took another look at the `ldconfig` output and noticed this:

```
libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib/libevent_pthreads-2.0.so.5
libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib/libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5
libevent_extra-2.0.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib/libevent_extra-2.0.so.5
libevent_core-2.0.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib/libevent_core-2.0.so.5
libevent-2.0.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib/libevent-2.0.so.5
```

There are no references to the base links, for example, I would expect to see links to these (`ls -la /usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib`):

```
libevent.so -> libevent-2.0.so.5.1.7
libevent_openssl.so -> libevent_openssl-2.0.so.5.1.7
libevent_core.so -> libevent_core-2.0.so.5.1.7
```

So either I am doing something wrong, or the system still does not know where to look to find `libevent.so`.

**-- Update #1 --**

I wasn't able to get libmemcached to compile without the warning notice, even after trying to compile using the following configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/_custom/app/libmemcached CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/lib"
```

I thought for sure this would work because I am directly passing the include and lib directories to the configure command. But it did not.

Comment: you need to tell where the source files are - not the so lib files.
into your script you see that event.h - tell to configure where the you put that file (the directory)

Comment: As another data point, I was able to build libmemcached 1.10 on Centos 6.3 by installing libevent-devel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and was about to give up on libmemcached when I noticed that the configure flag should be

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/include"
```

instead of

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/_custom/app/libevent/include"
```

Comment: Whoa, and this worked?

Comment: Yes, this worked.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for my english first.
my os: CentOS 6.3 mini without desktop x86_64, i haven't yum install libevent
i met same problem many times in different environment
Here is my installation process of libevent:

```
tar zxvf libevent-2.0.20-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-2.0.20-stable
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libevent
make
make install
```

before my install libmemcached-1.0.10
i tried

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libmemcached --with-lib-prefix=/usr/local/libevent --with-memcached=/usr/local/bin/
```

and

```
LIBEVENT_CPPFLAGS=/usr/local/libevent/include
LIBEVENT_LDFLAGS=/usr/local/libevent/lib
```

the problem also happend.
then i do some link like here:

```
ln -s /usr/local/libevent/include/* /usr/include/
ln -s /usr/local/libevent/lib/libevent* /usr/lib64/
```

it's done!
i think libmemcached locate libevent.so and event.h has some hard code.
wish my solution can help u.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest installing the `libevent-devel` package on the system. That will provide the header file listed in the error you posted, but the version may be older (1.4.13-1) than what you need for your `libmemcached`.

Looking at your sequence, I'd actually recommend removing the `config.cache` file in your `libmemcached` source directory, then rerunning the `./configure` for `libmemcached`. That should allow the process to recognize the changes you made to the library search paths.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, going to try it today. Just curious, before I run the `./configure` command I always run the `make clean` command, shouldn't `make clean` clear out any remnants of previous make attempts, i.e. the config.cache file?

Comment: Except in situations where the makefile hasn't been generated yet... Or if your configure fails on a dependency...

Comment: Ok, I tried the config.cache solution, but before/after `./configure` there was no config.cache file to be found. I think you are correct, the header file need to be available, and did find it, but it is located in `/usr/src/_custom/app/libevent/include` which the system doesn't appear to be aware of, so maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I updated post with another attempted solution, which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with a few seasoned Sysadmin guys from work, I opted to just do a `yum install memcached`. As with CentOS, one of the trade-offs is working with older versions of apps/libs, but CentOS maintainers will backport security fixes etc, so I figured I'll just go with the upstream version and save myself some headache.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have a proper answer, but I did notice when my freshly compiled tmux on CentOS told me

```
tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried this, and it worked:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib tmux
```

I'm not sure what the canonical/standard way of setting the system's LD_LIBRARY_PATH is, but it does not appear to be "horrible" per se if I stuck it into bashrc/zshrc.

**Edit:** Ah, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151600/340947) is one answer that elucidates the way to tell your system where the libraries live.